# How do I sort a generic list using a custom comparer?

Tags: delphi, sorting

I'm kinda a Delphi-newbie and I don't get how the Sort method of a TList of Records is called in order to sort the records by ascending integer value.
I have a record like the following:

```
 type
   TMyRecord = record
     str1: string;
     str2: string;
     intVal: integer;
   end;
```

And a generic list of such records:

```
TListMyRecord = TList<TMyRecord>;
```

Have tried to find a code-example in the help files and found this one:

```
MyList.Sort(@CompareNames);
```

Which I can't use, since it uses classes. So I tried to write my own compare function with a little different parameters:

```
function CompareIntVal(i1, i2: TMyRecord): Integer;
begin
  Result := i1.intVal - i2.intVal;
end;
```

But the compiler always throws a 'not enough parameters' - error when I call it with `open.Sort(CompareIntVal);`, which seems obvious; so I tried to stay closer to the help file:

```
function SortKB(Item1, Item2: Pointer): Integer;
begin
  Result:=PMyRecord(Item1)^.intVal - PMyRecord(Item2)^.intVal;
end;
```

with PMyRecord as `PMyRecord = ^TMyRecord;`

I have tried different ways of calling a function, always getting some error...

Answer (score 66, accepted):

The `Sort` overload you should be using is this one:

```
procedure Sort(const AComparer: IComparer<TMyRecord>);
```

Now, you can create an `IComparer<TMyRecord>` by calling `TComparer<TMyRecord>.Construct`. Like this:

```
var
  Comparison: TComparison<TMyRecord>;
....
Comparison := 
  function(const Left, Right: TMyRecord): Integer
  begin
    Result := Left.intVal-Right.intVal;
  end;
List.Sort(TComparer<TMyRecord>.Construct(Comparison));
```

I've written the `Comparison` function as an anonymous method, but you could also use a plain old style non-OOP function, or a method of an object.

One potential problem with your comparison function is that you may suffer from integer overflow. So you could instead use the default integer comparer.

```
Comparison := 
  function(const Left, Right: TMyRecord): Integer
  begin
    Result := TComparer<Integer>.Default.Compare(Left.intVal, Right.intVal);
  end;
```

It might be expensive to call `TComparer<Integer>.Default` repeatedly so you could store it away in a global variable:

```
var
  IntegerComparer: IComparer<Integer>;
....
initialization
  IntegerComparer := TComparer<Integer>.Default;
```

Another option to consider is to pass in the comparer when you create the list. If you only ever sort the list using this ordering then that's more convenient.

```
List := TList<TMyRecord>.Create(TComparer<TMyRecord>.Construct(Comparison));
```

And then you can sort the list with

```
List.Sort;
```

Comment: Thanks verry much!
Do I need to include anything in 'uses' besides the `uses
  Generics.Collections,...`, 'cause I get an 'undeclared' for `TComparison`and `IComparer`in `var
  Comparison: TComparison<TKanteRecord>;
  IntegerComparer: IComparer<Integer>;`?

Comment: You also need Generics.Defaults. Have you found the RTL source code yet. That would help you.

Comment: @David, are you sure `TComparer` is a good choice for a code you provided ? `TComparer` is meant to be the abstract base class. I'd suggest to use `TDelegatedComparer` for your code.

Comment: @TLama Yes I am sure of that: `TComparer<T>.Construct(Comparison)` is implemented with a call to `TDelegatedComparer<T>.Create(Comparison)`.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan The TList<T> does not have a constructor that accept a TComparer<T> as an input parameter in Delphi 10.2. Could you give compilable examples?

Comment: @Bitman The code here does compile. It does not pass a `TComparer<T>` to any constructor.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Definitely not! I interested in your last "solution" that uses a TList<T>.create( IComparer<T> ) constructor and a parameterless TList<T>.Sort method call.

Comment: @bitman I'm pretty sure it compiles but I can't check right now

Comment: @bitman As I thought, the code in the answer compiles. You must have transcribed it incorrectly.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan As I wrote. I was interested in the second solution. The section after "Another option...". There is no example for this solution.

Comment: @bitman yes there is, that's the code I checked, and it compiles just fine. Instead of asking what's wrong with my code you'll need to study yours. You made a mistake somewhere.

Answer (score 19):

The concise answer:

```
uses
  .. System.Generics.Defaults // Contains TComparer

myList.Sort(
  TComparer<TMyRecord>.Construct(
    function(const Left, Right: TMyRecord): Integer
    begin
      Result := Left.intVal - Right.intVal;
    end
  )
);
```

Answer (score 2):

I want to share my solution (based on the input I have gathered here).

It's a standard setup. A filedata class that holds data of a single file in a generic TObjectList. The list has the two private attributes fCurrentSortedColumn and fCurrentSortAscending to control the sort order. The AsString-method is the path and filename combined.

```
function TFileList.SortByColumn(aColumn: TSortByColums): boolean;
var
  Comparison: TComparison<TFileData>;
begin
  result := false;
  Comparison := nil;

  case aColumn of
    sbcUnsorted   : ;
    sbcPathAndName: begin
                      Comparison := function(const Left, Right: TFileData): integer
                                    begin
                                      Result := TComparer<string>.Default.Compare(Left.AsString,Right.AsString);
                                    end;
                    end;
    sbcSize       : begin
                      Comparison := function(const Left, Right: TFileData): integer
                                    begin
                                      Result := TComparer<int64>.Default.Compare(Left.Size,Right.Size);
                                      if Result = 0 then
                                        Result := TComparer<string>.Default.Compare(Left.AsString,Right.AsString);
                                    end;
                    end;
    sbcDate       : begin
                      Comparison := function(const Left, Right: TFileData): integer
                                    begin
                                      Result := TComparer<TDateTime>.Default.Compare(Left.Date,Right.Date);
                                      if Result = 0 then
                                        Result := TComparer<string>.Default.Compare(Left.AsString,Right.AsString);
                                    end;
                    end;
    sbcState      : begin
                      Comparison := function(const Left, Right: TFileData): integer
                                    begin
                                      Result := TComparer<TFileDataTestResults>.Default.Compare(Left.FileDataResult,Right.FileDataResult);
                                      if Result = 0 then
                                        Result := TComparer<string>.Default.Compare(Left.AsString,Right.AsString);
                                    end;
                     end;
  end;

  if assigned(Comparison) then
  begin
    Sort(TComparer<TFileData>.Construct(Comparison));

    // Control the sort order
    if fCurrentSortedColumn = aColumn then
      fCurrentSortAscending := not fCurrentSortAscending
    else begin
      fCurrentSortedColumn := aColumn;
      fCurrentSortAscending := true;
    end;

    if not fCurrentSortAscending then
      Reverse;

    result := true;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a much simpler modified sort function to alphabetize a TList of records or nonstandard list of items.

Example

```
PList = ^TContact;
    TContact = record             //Record for database of user contact records
      firstname1 : string[20];
      lastname1 : string[20];
       phonemobile : Integer;       //Fields in the database for contact info
      phonehome : Integer;
      street1 : string;
      street2 : string;

 type
    TListSortCompare = function (Item1,
                                Item2: TContact): Integer;
var
  Form1: TForm1;
  Contact : PList;         //declare record database for contacts
  arecord : TContact;
  Contacts : TList;   //List for the Array of Contacts

function CompareNames(i1, i2: TContact): Integer;
begin
   Result := CompareText(i1.lastname1, i2.lastname1) ;
end;
```

and the function to call to sort your list

```
Contacts.Sort(@CompareNames);
```

Comment: You might want to clean up your code sample a bit. Remove unused variables. Add usage example. Correct the syntax.

Comment: The original question was about sorting a generic list, while this example is using the standard TList (list of pointers), which is a different scenario.