# How to sort a TArray containing TPair<Word, MyRecordType> entries

Tags: arrays, sorting, delphi, generics

I want to sort a `TArray` containing entries of a self defined `TPair<>`. I tried to follow this one, but the compiler always complains that he needs an object record or classtype (E2018):

[How to sort a generic array containing records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13252169/how-do-i-sort-a-generic-list-using-a-custom-comparer).

My code:

```
type
  TFailureEntry = TPair<System.Word, TMyFailureRecord>;

procedure TMyClass.GetFailureAbbreviations;
var
  FailureArray: TArray<TFailureEntry>;
  Comparison: TComparison<TFailureEntry>;
begin
  // derive the array contents from a dictionary
  FailureArray := FFailureDictionary.ToArray;

  Comparison :=
    function(const Left, Right: TFailureEntry): Integer
    begin
      Result := Left.Key-Right.Key;
    end;

  FailureArray.Sort(TComparer<TFailureEntry>.Construct(Comparison));
end;
```

The compiler complains at the .sort call.

Answer (score 1):

An array cannot have a method - in this case no Sort method. Use TArray.Sort instead:

```
TArray.Sort<TFailureEntry>(FailureArray, TComparer<TFailureEntry>.Construct(Comparison));
```